# How to make total in footer using datatable in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, datatable

I am working on codeigniter application. I am stuck somewhere. below is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datatable').dataTable( {
        "fnFooterCallback": function ( nRow, aaData, iDataStart, iDataEnd ) {
            /* Calculate the total market share for all browsers in this table (ie inc. outside
             * the pagination
             */
            var iTotalMarket = 0;
            for ( var i=0 ; i<aaData.length ; i++ )
            {
                iTotalMarket += aaData[i][3]*1;
            }

            /* Calculate the market share for browsers on this page */
            var iPageMarket = 0;
            for ( var i=iDataStart ; i<iDataEnd ; i++ )
            {
                iPageMarket += aaData[i][3]*1;
            }
            var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
            nCells[1].innerHTML = parseInt(iPageMarket);
```

when I filter rows, it shows wrong code
What's the problem. thanks for any help

Comment: Can you give us an example of what it is showing and what you expect it to show?

Comment: When i filter rows, it shows wrong total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@deepak

you are missing aiDisplay variable in your function
use the following code to solve your problem

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datatable').dataTable( {
        "fnFooterCallback": function ( nRow, aaData, iDataStart, iDataEnd,aiDisplay ) {
            /* Calculate the total market share for all browsers in this table (ie inc. outside
             * the pagination
             */
            var iTotalMarket = 0;
            for ( var i=0 ; i<aaData.length ; i++ )
            {
                iTotalMarket += aaData[i][3]*1;
            }

            /* Calculate the market share for browsers on this page */
            var iPageMarket = 0;
            for ( var i=iDataStart ; i<iDataEnd ; i++ )
            {
                iPageMarket += aaData[aiDisplay[i]][3]*1;
            }
var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
            nCells[1].innerHTML = parseInt(iPageMarket);
}
} );
} );
```